# Multi threaded data.table in R much slower than one using single thread

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, data.table

Here comes a simple example:

```
#Load libraries:
library(data.table)
library(tictoc)

#Set the number of threads:
setDTthreads(1)

#Set seed:
set.seed(1)

#Create a small example:
n_f<-2500
n_w<-sample(1:1000,n_f,replace=TRUE)
n_t<-sample(c("","AS","E","D","F"),n_f,replace=TRUE)
yearmonth<-ifelse(nchar(seq(1,12))==1,paste("0",seq(1,12),sep=""),seq(1,12))
yearmonth<-paste(rep(seq(1996,2018),each=12),yearmonth,sep="")

#Create a large synthetic data set:
data_final<-list("vector")
for (i in 1:length(yearmonth)){
  data_aux<-data.table(fid=rep(1:n_f,n_w),type=rep(n_t,n_w),date=yearmonth[i])
  data_final[[i]]<-data_aux
}

#Combine everything together:
data_final<-rbindlist(data_final)

#Do the calculation:
tic()
data_final[,nr_unique_type:=uniqueN(type),by=c("fid","date")]
toc()
```

On my machine the calculation takes about 23 seconds. On the other hand, if I do not specify setDTthreads(1)  (and it uses 32 cores), it runs for 53 seconds. Maybe somebody could explain why with multithreading it is so much slower.

I am using `R 3.6.0` and `data.table 1.12.8`

Comment: A [known issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3739) for `uniqueN`... something we are working on. You can read there and a few other issues around parallelism for why

Comment: @MichaelChirico one small question, it seems that in data.table 1.11.8 uniqueN is faster than in 1.12.8 (with setDTthreads(1)). Do you have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: in 1.11.8 forder was not parallel so uniqueN was single threaded, just replace it with `length(unique(.))`

Comment: could you check if `remotes::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table@subsetDT1")` resolves the problem?

Comment: @jangorecki, it works now, times are :17 sec with 16 threads, 17 seconds with 32 threads and 17 seconds with 48 threads. Is it safe to use this version?

Comment: It should be very soon on CRAN, thanks for checking

Answer (score 2):

As per discussion in comments. This was known inefficiency caused by forming a team of CPU thread even when computing relatively small tasks.
This has been improved in recent version of data.table (1.12.10).
That has been verified by OP.
It is not longer needed to use `setDTthreads(1)` to avoid this inefficiency.